# UICollectionView cell size ContentView Issue

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionViewCell in storyboard the cell. The cell size is 45 for first 6 cells and 50 for the last cell.

Storyboard cell size has width = 60.

The following issue occurs when running on iOS Simulator 4s.

[image]

If you see the cell at location 2,4,6 there is a red background of UICollectionView.

I get the following in *layoutSubView* of the subclass.

```
Frame = {{0, 0}, {50, 60}}
Frame = {{0, 0}, {45, 60}}
Frame = {{0, 0}, {45, 60}}
Frame = {{0, 0}, {45, 60}}
Frame = {{0, 0}, {45, 60}}
Frame = {{0, 0}, {45, 60}}
Frame = {{0, 0}, {45, 60}}


- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    NSLog(@"Frame = %@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.bounds));
    self.contentView.frame = self.bounds;
}
```

Also, added the resizing in awakefromnib which did not work.

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{
    [super awakeFromNib];

   self.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth ;
}
```

The above result which is printed is correct, the sizes are perfect.

Adding the following in ViewController also did not work

```
-(CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section{
    return 0.0;
}
-(CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section{
    return 0.0;
}
```

A  demo project is available for some time at [url.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i03ys0s7sebokh0/Collection.zip?dl=0)

On further investigation I found was because of scaling simulator. The screens are with a 4s simulator. I don't know if on device it will cause any issue.

100% => result Ok
75%  => red background lines appear
50%  => result Ok
33%  => result Ok
25%  => red background lines appear

[image] [image] [image]
[image][image]

Comment: Can you provide a little more info about your layout and are the sizes of your `celloectionViewCells' different? If so then you probably need to use custom layout for your collectionView instead of flowLayout.

Answer (score 0):

try to set the constraints of the collectionView like this
[image]

Comment: Did you ever fix this issue?