# Spacing in CollectionView Cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

How to remove spacing in collectionview cells. I want to get 18 rows and 22 columns which should fit according to frame height and width. I override the UICollectionViewFlowLayout but there is a space after last column in collection view.
Can some one please help me to solve this.

Comment: Height is independent here. For width You need to manage it. Give proper width & Space according to your requirement.

Comment: i take screen width and divide it by 22.
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{float cellWidth = screenWidth / [self.advncdObj.motionGridX integerValue];                                                                                    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(cellWidth, cellHeight);}

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do it----

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Collection view
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 30;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MagazineCell *mCell = (MagazineCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];

    mCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    return mCell;
}

#pragma mark Collection view layout things
// Layout: Set cell size
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"SETTING SIZE FOR ITEM AT INDEX %d", indexPath.row);
    CGSize mElementSize = CGSizeMake(104, 104);
    return mElementSize;
}
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0.0;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return 2.0;
}

// Layout: Set Edges
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:
(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
   // return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,8,0,8);  // top, left, bottom, right
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,0);  // top, left, bottom, right
}

@end
```

And the other way-------->
1.Override standard flow layout.
2.Add implementation like that:

```
- (NSArray *) layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSArray *answer = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];

    for(int i = 1; i < [answer count]; ++i) {
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *currentLayoutAttributes = answer[i];
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *prevLayoutAttributes = answer[i - 1];
        NSInteger maximumSpacing = 0;
        NSInteger origin = CGRectGetMaxX(prevLayoutAttributes.frame);

        if(origin + maximumSpacing + currentLayoutAttributes.frame.size.width < self.collectionViewContentSize.width) {
            CGRect frame = currentLayoutAttributes.frame;
            frame.origin.x = origin + maximumSpacing;
            currentLayoutAttributes.frame = frame;
        }
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: I override and used the above method but in this case collection view is not fitting to the device width instead a small space after collection view

Comment: in storyboard- collection view size, have you selected minimum spacing for cells as 0.0 ??

Comment: i have added collection view programmatically

Comment: can you edit your question and add screenshot of what exactly is happening??!!

Comment: try my first answer and return 0 for minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex. and adjust your other requirements accordingly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111405/discussion-between-raj-and-user1728987).

Answer (score 0):

`UICollectionViewFlowLayoutDelegate` method will help you..

**Option 1:**

```
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:  (UICollectionView *)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section  
{
    return 0; // This is the minimum inter item spacing, can be more
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flow = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
flow.itemSize = CGSizeMake(cellWidth, cellHeight);
flow.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
flow.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0;
flow.minimumLineSpacing = 0;
[mainCollectionView reloadData];
mainCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = flow;
```

***Last line is important where we are assigning the layout***

if you need more space to arrange your cells adjust the edgeInsets also.and also you can refer this link [iOS - UICollectionView spacing still there when set to 0 - How to set with no spacing between cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19250284/ios-uicollectionview-spacing-still-there-when-set-to-0-how-to-set-with-no-sp)

Comment: I dont want spacing between cells.

Comment: Just try with by giving `return 0` in that method

Answer (score 0):

```
#pragma mark Collection View Delegate
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
   return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return 330;
}
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    return CGSizeMake(Screen_Width/22, Screen_Width/22);
}
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
   return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0,0, 0);
}
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    customcell *cell = (customcell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"customcell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

            if (cell == nil)
            {
                NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"customcell" owner:self options:nil];
                cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
            }
     return cell;
}
```

Comment: Try this one. This solution may help u